# How to detect uninstall event in Cordova app using node.js using React

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cordova, reactjs

I want to clear cache of my application when App is uninstalled from any device (android or IOS).
Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess after uninstalling app, all relevant app data will be erased.

Answer (score 0):

iOS applications are contained within their Sandbox. With few exceptions (like keychain or photo library) the only data your app has access to, or can write to, is in that Sandbox. Uninstalling an app on iOS equals deleting the application sandbox. That means deleting app removes all data stored by that application, including your cache.